# Dropdown Menu with Submenu CSS HTML

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu with submenu that align with the parent items in HTML/CSS, but I'm having trouble getting the alignment right.
Right now, the submenus just appear at the top of the list instead of at the same level as their parent.

Here's the fiddle code for what I'm talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/h96jda5h/

I think it has something to do with the CSS nav properties, but I'm not sure what:

```
#nav ul{ list-style-type:none; padding:0; margin:0; }
#nav ul li{ display:inline-block; }
#nav ul li:hover{ background-color:#FFF; }
#nav ul li a,visited{ display:block; padding:15px; text-decoration:none; }
#nav ul li:hover >ul{ display:block;}
#nav ul ul{display:none; position:absolute; background-color:#FFF; min-width:200px; }
#nav ul ul li{ display:block;}
#nav ul ul li:hover{ background-color:#F1F7F7; }
#nav ul ul li"hover > ul{ display: block; }
#nav ul ul ul{ margin: -52px 0 0 200px; background-color:#FFF; }
```

I searched this website for the answer and found help with the 'sub' class for li, but it doesn't appear to be working for me for some reason.
Any advice would be so helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing one single css instruction:

`position: relative`

in here

`#nav ul ul li{ display:block;}`

Explanation:

Absolute positioned elements refer to the first parent that's absolute or relative positioned. Right now, the sub-menu was taking in consideration the ul and not the li

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position: relative` to the absolutely positioned `ul`'s parent `li`.

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to their nearest ancestor. Any parent element with a position other than `position: static` (default) is considered an ancestor so adding `position: relative` to the `li` element makes it the closest ancestor of it's child `ul`.

http://learnlayout.com/position.html

https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

With your current example, you can do it like this.

```
.sub { position: relative; }
```

or like this

```
#nav ul ul li { 
  display:block;
  position: relative;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h96jda5h/1/